# Convert CSV to parquet using Spark, preserving the partitioning

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I'm trying to use Spark to convert a bunch of csv files to parquet, with the interesting case that the input csv files are already "partitioned" by directory.
All the input files have the same set of columns.
The input files structure looks like :

```
/path/dir1/file1.csv
/path/dir1/file2.csv
/path/dir2/file3.csv
/path/dir3/file4.csv
/path/dir3/file5.csv
/path/dir3/file6.csv
```

I'd like to read those files with Spark and write their data to a parquet table in hdfs, preserving the partitioning (partitioned by input directory), and such as there is a single output file per partition.
The output files strucutre should look like :

```
hdfs://path/dir=dir1/part-r-xxx.gz.parquet
hdfs://path/dir=dir2/part-r-yyy.gz.parquet
hdfs://path/dir=dir3/part-r-zzz.gz.parquet
```

The best solution I have found so far is to loop among the input directories, loading the csv files in a dataframe and to write the dataframe in the target partition in the parquet table.
But this not efficient since I want a single output file per partition, the writing to hdfs is a single tasks that blocks the loop.
I wonder how to achieve this with a maximum of parallelism (and without shuffling the data in the cluster).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Rename your input directories changing `dirX` to `dir=dirX`. Then perform:

```
spark.read.csv('/path/').coalesce(1).write.partitionBy('dir').parquet('output')
```

If you cannot rename directories, you can use Hive Metastore. Create external table and one partition per every directory. Then load this table and rewrite using above pattern.

Comment: This is spark 2.0, right ? I'm still on 1.6 and I'm using the databricks csv reader. Are you sure that this method will make it such as all the csv files from the same input directory will be loaded by the same node ? Otherwise the coalesce will create shuffling.

Comment: Yes, with 1.X you need load spark-csv package and it should work too.

Comment: It works with the spark-csv package but it creates shuffling, as it does not enforce data locality across the input directories.

Comment: It's strange, the only place when shuffling could appear is coalesce and coalesce does not shuffle by default: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.coalesce. But I tested in only on local mode... What makes you think that shuffling appears? And data locality is not preserved?

Comment: My bad, coalesce(1) does not shuffle, but it makes the entire process single-threaded. So it takes ages ... Instead of coalesce, repartidion('dir') is a better choice. It creates shuffling but is still faster than coalesce(1)

Answer (score 0):

Best solution I've found so far (no shuffling and as many threads as input dirs) :

- Create an rdd of input dirs, with as many partitions as input dirs
- Transform it to an rdd of input files (preserving the partitions by dirs)
- Flat-map it with a custom csv parser
- Convert rdd to dataframe
- Write dataframe to parquet table partitioned by dirs

It requires to write his own parser. I could not find a solution to preserve the partitioning using sc.textfile or the databricks csv parser.